# maven is changing package name to camel case

Tags: java, maven

I am building my project using maven and I am facing this weird behavior where maven is renaming the package name to camel case when compiling/building the project.

`my source package is: c:\my-data\java\src\main\java\com\sample\thisone`

`my compiled class path is : c:\my-data\java\target\classes\com\sample\thisOne`

Notice the last word. I am not sure why maven is doing that, any idea.I am building my code using `mvn clean install`

Here is the information from menifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: tyaashi
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.3
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_65
```

Comment: what is your 'package' statement in the class that's there?

Comment: it is `com.sample.thisone`

Comment: the only reason that would be camel cased is if the package statement within the class has 'package com.sample.thisOne' either in the class or package-info.java - the compiler, under maven, will be the one generating that output.

Comment: `c:\my-data\java\src\main\java\com\sample\thisone` is **not** a valid package name. It is a filesystem path. Post the relevant parts of your pom! What is the `groupId` in there? Further, I suspect you are confusing package and class name. What is the `artifactId` in your pom?

Comment: @Siking - I do know that it is filesystem path. I can not paste the actual name due to security concern of my company .. if that makes you happy the package name is `com.sample.thisone` and it is being converted to `com.sample.thisOne` and this is a valid problem I am facing so you should have checked before giving -1 to question

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your pom!

Comment: <artifactId>sample-core</artifactId>

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your pom! What is the `groupId` in there?

Comment: `    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
`

Comment: The only other thing I can suggest is to grep through your source for any occurrence of the camel-cased word.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to find the issue and fixed it.

It was happening because my hibernate mapping file was stored in camelcase folder under `src\main\resources`. I appreciate everyone help.